# automatically generating a map with the fields of a class

Tags: java, lombok

I have the following class

```
@Data
public class CMC{

  String f1;
  String f2;
  String f3;      
  public Map<String, Supplier<String>> valuesMap() {
    return ImmutableMap.<String, Supplier<String>>builder()
        .put("f1", this::f1)
        .put("f2", this::f2)
        .put("f3", this::f3)
        .build();
  }

}
```

As you can see I have a few fields and a map for that contains each field pointing to a function that returns the value of that field.

The problem with this solution is that a developer may get here and add a new field but forgets to add it to a map.

Is there a way to automate this process?

I was hoping for something like lombok to help me with this case. It's a common thing to need a list of the field from a class and have access to their values.

To solve this I would create an annotation and then somehow use reflection to obtain my desired behavior but I suppose something like this has been already implemented in some tools.

Comment: Catch with a unit test?  Use reflection to detect all String fields and assert the field name is a key in the map, unless specifically ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into: [Class::getDeclaredFields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--); [Class::getSuperclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--); and [Field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html).  Together, they should be able to get pretty much what you're looking for...  Something like:

```
final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
Class<?> klass = this.getClass();
while (klass != null) {
    for (final Field field : klass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (!field.isAccessible()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
        }
        map.put(field.getName(), field.get(this));
    }
    klass = klass.getSuperclass();
}
```

You'll need to handle exceptions, work out where to call this, and confirm if you want to do it for *all* fields (`private`, etc.) or just some, whether to lazily cache the value somewhere, and whether everything needs converting to a `String` (in which case the `Object` in the `map` can be changed).